# Disable trigger effects in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

I have a function where there is:

```
alter table a disable trigger trig1;
some code
alter table a enable trigger trig1;
```

It basicaly disables the trigger for the purpose of specific operations.

My question is:

What will happen if at the same time the trigger is disabled, another user from another session makes operations on `a` which relies on that trigger to be triggered?

Answer (score 4):

[`ALTER TABLE ... DISABLE TRIGGER ...` takes a `SHARE ROW EXCLUSIVE` lock](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-altertable.html). So no relevant concurrent operation *can* happen on the table:

> `DISABLE/ENABLE ... TRIGGER`
>
> This command acquires a `SHARE ROW EXCLUSIVE` lock.

where [the docs on lock levels](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/explicit-locking.html) say that:

> `SHARE ROW EXCLUSIVE`
>
> ... This mode protects a table against concurrent data changes, and is self-exclusive so that only one session can hold it at a time.

Despite the name, a `SHARE ROW EXCLUSIVE` lock is a table-level lock. The name is historical.

Now, PostgreSQL has a mechanism you can (ab)use to skip triggers firing on certain operations. It's intended for replication tools like Slony-I and Londiste, and is called `session_replication_role`. Be aware that using it for other purposes may have "surprising" consequences if you then start using a logical replication tool.

Comment: It takes a lock on the whole table!?

Comment: @mm Yes, it'll continue to permit reads but blocks all writes. It's an `ALTER TABLE` subcommand so that's not too surprising. What you're looking for seems to be more like a session level trigger setting. PostgreSQL doesn't really have anything like that yet.